# Display the product count in categories with static block in magento

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, category-products

I want to display product count of available in product category. In my website i added H1 title through static block, so i want to know the technique to **show product count near to H1 title.**

See blow my website image-

[image: Want to show total number of product count through static block]

Please suggest me how can I product count like below added image -

[image]

Please let me know any code to show count

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

What're you going to need is a custom block.

### Create the block

Create a Magento module. Declare a block short code in `config.xml`; for ease we'll be using `demo`:

```
    <models>
        <demo>
            <class>YourModule_Demo_Block</class>
        </demo>
    </models>
```

We can now refer to any block class in that path with a short code. Let's define the new class. Because we don't need to render a template and we'll be using some text generated by a resource model's query we don't need to use a template block.

```
<?php

class YourModule_Demo_Block_Productcount extends Mage_Core_Block_Text
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $productCount = $this->getProductCount();
        $this->setText($productCount);
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductCount()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        return (int)$collection->getSize();
    }
}
```

How does this work?

- The `_construct` method is called right at the beginning of the block creation and calls setText on the `getProductCount` method.
- `getProductCount` queries the database to get the total product count

What this **does not do** is filter that collection to be targeted for the category that you're viewing. I can't do all your work for you!! ;)

### Adding to a static block

So the hard work is done. Now to add to the static block. In your static block text you'll want to insert the following code:

```
{{block type="demo/productcount" name="catalog.productcount"}}
```

And that's it! It should work.

### More work

Your next feat will be to modify your Class to pass in and filter by the currently viewed category. I won't do this for you - but here's a hint:

```
Mage::registry('current_category')
```

That function should return the category model for the currently visible category :)

Happy Magento-ing!